# keep connection alive in golang as API for android

Tags: android, api, http, sockets, go

I am using golang as API for android app and should make lots of connection to server(golang API) such as auto-complete-text. I use json for data transferring.

1. Is there any way to keep connection alive and just send and receive data ?
2. What is difference between `Socket` (like java `Socket`) and `http.ListenAndServe()` in golang ?
   This is for android side:

```
public class MakeConnection extends Thread {
    String data;
    Context context;
    ConnListener listener;

    public MakeConnection(String data, Context context, ConnListener listener) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void run() {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://192.168.1.1:8080").openConnection();
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
            connection.setReadTimeout(0);
            connection.connect();

            OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(Math.max(connection.getContentLength(), 100000));
            while (true) {
                String readLine = reader.readLine();
                if (readLine == null) {
                    break;
                }
                result.append(readLine);
            }
            listener.Connected(result.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            listener.Failed(e);
        } 
    }
}
```

This is for golang:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleConnection)
    _ = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handleConnection(rw http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

    var jj map[string]interface{}
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: (pseudo explanation):you have to understand connections, tcp, socket, http are just just like a extended  classes java (android),tcp is base class for socket, same with the http, you need to use sockets, opening a tcp connection and keeping it alive is called a socket, opening a tcp connection and closing after data s received or sent is called http request

Comment: use ```net.Listen("tcp","localhost:8080)``` to setup a tcp socket

Comment: @Yadu So how to prevent malicious use of socket from hackers? For example they can open lots of socket and keep it open on my server.

Comment: expect first message within n seconds to be a token or any type of authentication or else drop the connection from server, if need easier setup there are frameworks for go, like gorilla socket or gobwas etc

Comment: use gorilla websocket, listen for a http connection -> verify auth header-> upgrade to socket, from a android client dial a url with ws:// rather than https://